# SQL table not returning all records

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am connecting to an SQL database via SQL Server Management Studio and retrieving records from a single table using a SELECT statement. The records retrieved do not include sections of the dataset that I know exist. I know this because I can query the database using a legacy app which gives me the complete set of records. Unfortunately the app is not supported by the developers and there is no documentation regarding the inner workings of the app and how it connects.

This is an example of the query I'm using in SSMS. No records are returned.

```
SELECT *
FROM [Sprint].[dbo].[repair]
WHERE [rep_date] >= CONVERT(date, '2022-11-01') AND [rep_date] <= CONVERT(date, '2022-11-30')
  AND [rep_bld_id] LIKE 'ST%'
```

After running the query via the legacy app the missing records appear in SSMS. I suspect some kind of caching issue but I'm not sure.

It appears to be limited to only one table. Other tables in the database seem to work as expected.
I've checked the permissions on the database and cannot see anything untoward.

[rep_date] is a datetime field. [rep_bld_id] is varchar

Comment: It's incredibly hard for us to help you with this information. 
I would start by removing parts of the where clause, and see where you get unexpected results. So, first remove [rep_bld_id] LIKE 'ST%', then [rep_date] <= CONVERT(date, '2022-11-30'), then [rep_date] >= CONVERT(date, '2022-11-01')
Another common failure mode is connecting to the wrong database.

Comment: Something to consider... just because a column has `date` in its name doesn't mean it's actually a column of data type `date`. All too often we see people munging dates and datetimes into char-based columns so, if that's the case, it's probably some date format that's different than the session's current `SET DATEFORMAT` option.

Comment: Are is `rep_date` an actual `date` or `datetime` field ? If it's a `datetime`, do the missing values occur on `2022-11-30`? When comparing a date and datetime, the time part matters. `rep_date <= '2022-11-30'` is identical to `rep_date <= '2022-11-30 00:00:00'` and excludes any record reported after midnight. If you want all records in November use `rep_date>= '20221101' and rep_date < '20221201'`

Comment: You can use the unambiguous `YYYYMMDD` format instead of `cast('yyyy-mm-dd' as date) `or `CONVERT`. If you use the "new" date types, `date`, `datetime2` and `datetimeoffset`, `YYYY-MM-DD` is also unambiguous. Unfortunately, in the legacy `datetime` type that most people still use, `YYYY-MM-DD` is affected by the `DATEFORMAT` setting and could be translated as `YYYY-DD-MM`. That's why you see so many T-SQL questions using `YYYYMMDD`.

Comment: Thanks everybody for your comments. I've tried the above and I'm still seeing the issue. I tried the same query for Sep-2022 which returned no records. I then queried the database using the legacy app for the same time period and build id and got 25 records which I'd expect. I then re-ran the query in SSMS and got the 25 records as well.

Comment: This tells us nothing. Except perhaps that the legacy app doesn't execute the query you think it does. You can capture the actual query on the server by using the XEvent Profiler or Extended Events. In SSMS, under the server node there should be an `XEvent Profiler` node with two sessions, Standard and TSQL. This may already be active.

Comment: "After running the query via the legacy app the missing records appear in SSMS" so you run that exact query in SSMS, no records, you run some query in your app, then you run that exact query again in SSMS, and this time get records? That truly doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1):

If `rep_date` datatype is `DateTime` the value will save as `2023-03-02 00:00:00` so try to cast `rep_date` also

try to run below query

```
SELECT *
FROM [Sprint].[dbo].[repair]
WHERE cast([rep_date] as date) between CONVERT(date, '2022-11-01 00:00:00') AND 
CONVERT(date, '2022-11-30 23:59:59')
AND [rep_bld_id] LIKE 'ST%'
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks again everybody. As Panagiotis Kanavos suggested. I used the XEvent Profiler function which showed me the query being executed by the legacy app. Turns out it's not a simple select query after all. Should be able to recreate what I need now.